# js alternative to jquery load method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to throw together a single js file that includes the functionality of jquery's .load(), as well as the methods, in an effort to link only to a single js file, rather than both jquery and the load methods.

Instead of

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="load.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

this

```
<script src="load_including-necessary-js-for-load-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So basically I'm trying to extract only the necessary code from within jquery that makes .load() work and include it in the file with the load methods.

Comment: It is an XMLHttpRequest call, start there.

Comment: WHY? jQuery size is about 32K, it's cached by most users. just use jQuery.

Comment: You can take a look at http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/ for browsing the source code and then copy/clip your own ~framework. But I can't recommend it.

Comment: Yes, minified jQuery is small enough there is really no need to do this.  It really would cause more issues than anything else, as who knows what `load()` relies on internally.  To make the page speedier, you could stick all of the content of the JS files into one (however, this becomes one more thing to document and maintain).  If you are doing this due to a conflict issue with another library, look into jQuery's `noConflict` option.

Comment: If your goal is to *"link only to a single js file"* link a single file that includes jQuery and your scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggest, instead, that you use something along the lines of html5boilerplate's jQuery call:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

1. Accessing it via the CDN ensures high-speed delivery of the jQuery code that is used by thousands of other pages/users on a constant basis,
2. ... which also means that that code is most likely cached in your users' browsers ...
3. ... which equates to highly-tested code that you're really not "paying for" in terms of overall load time. The second line, of course, allows you to offer a copy of it from your own site, in case the CDN has a hiccup, or you need to be testing offline (in which case, AJAX is borked for you any way you look at it, anyhow...).

OTHERWISE, check out the instructions on jQuery's Github: https://github.com/jquery/jquery#how-to-build-your-own-jquery and read up on building your own... they have instructions, there for excluding modules that you don't want from the library.

After that, you'll probably want to use some kind of bundling script to bundle all your JS (your custom jQuery build + your scripts) together, if you want to reduce everything to one call.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know your reason why you cannot use all jquery library, but you still can write own js script and use [onload or document.load, window.load](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) its you reduce your code. If you need jQuery load() ... read and try to first comment of your question or use all small(own) jQuery library than waste of your time with this.